# Event Registration

Tags: php, drupal, e-commerce, registration

How can I create a site like http://www.eventbrite.com/ in drupal.

If its not possible in drupal what should I probably use.

More specifics --

1. Users can add their own events, add pricing. Out of that pricing the website can keep a certain % say 5%, when users purchase tickets. The commission can be on per event basis and cannot be changed by users, only admin can do that.
2. Free events can be also added.
3. It should also have event management features like artist management, portfolio management.
4. The event creators should have a profile which can be rated by the users so that they can have profile like system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very general, man... I'd use Event, Date, Location, Views and CCK modules. If you want a more specific answer, make your question more specific as well.

Comment: I have added the more specifics.

Comment: Ouch, now that's something I don't know how to achieve. User profiles are an inbuilt feature, you can extend them (to a degree). I guess you could add a rating system (Voting API and Fivestar modules should do nicely). Management - you can add a view with visible filters for that, I suppose. The events should probably be treated like products in Übercart, but I've never worked with this module (set of modules, actually), so I've no idea to what extent you can add the features you're interested in.

Comment: The main problem is users adding their own events and the admin setting up the commission. Management features can also be achieved via CiviCrm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Set up a site using Drupal and then try out this module:

http://drupal.org/project/signup  This module is designed to help you easily allow users to register for events you create on your site.